# Remove a message that the bot waited for using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Basically, im trying to make an autorole bot that takes a message from the user and then deletes the message and updates the role message after. The code I have so far is:

````py
  @commands.command()
  @commands.has_any_role(786342585479593984, 787715167437324330)
  async def rrtest(self, ctx, *, msg):
    loop = True
    j = "\n"

    messagetext = [msg]
    rolemessage = await ctx.send(f"```{j.join(messagetext)}```")

    message = await ctx.send("Hold on!")
    time.sleep(2)

    while loop:
      await message.edit(content="```Type the role you want to assign \n\nNo need to mention, just type the role name```")
      msg = await self.client.wait_for('message', check=self.check(ctx.author), timeout=30)
      # ^^^ this is the message i want to delete
````

what code would i use to delete `msg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method `.delete()`

```py
await msg.delete()
```

Also use `await asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep` so it doesn't block you whole code.